# JSEncrypt to PHP Asymmetric Encryption

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, encryption-asymmetric, jsencrypt

I am trying to do an Asymmetric encryption from client to server with the client having the public key and the server the private.

On the client side I am using JSEncrypt in javascript to encrypt using my public key.  From there I use AJAX to send the encrypted data to my PHP script.  I try to use `openssl_private_decrypt()` to decrypt the data, but it always returns false.  I have tried telling it to expect different padding, even though I am sure it is PKCS1.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is all the relevant code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function getpubkey(){ //Gets Public Key from server
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        pubkey = this.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "PHP/ajax.php", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("do=getpub");
}


function encryptdata(plaintext){ //Encrypts argument with Public Key
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(pubkey);
var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt(plaintext);
return encrypted;
}


function login(){ //Sends login data to server and displays response on page
getpubkey();
var encuser = encryptdata(document.getElementById('username').value);
var encpass = encryptdata(document.getElementById('password').value);
encuser = window.btoa(encuser);
encpass = window.btoa(encpass);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "PHP/ajax.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("do=login&param1="+encuser+"&param2="+encpass);

}
```

PHP (ajax.php):

```
if (!isset($_POST['do'])){
header("Location: ../index.php");
die();
}

$do = $_POST['do'];

if(isset($_POST['param1'])){
$param1 = $_POST['param1'];
}

if(isset($_POST['param2'])){
$param2 = $_POST['param2'];
}


$allow = 1;
require("../KEYS/priv.php"); //Contains $priv which holds the private key
if(openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($param1), $username, $priv, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING)){
    $return = $username;
}
else{
    $return = "Decrypt Failed";
}

if(isset($return)){
echo $return;
}
```

priv.php:

```
<?php

if (!isset($allow)){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    die();
}

$priv = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

?>
```

My Keys:

Public:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtzAVRzbQWzZi7wjqA/0m
>   agqlWQfKJhrfnCuytqwNR0rMKk+hGx1c+1YaPsN0ZMdBVWyBWJYWzlCjWOKx1vnY
>   gBb3MPXn1QvGkrv+WtXX3VQRsPjWtjaAqLYdjP/m64+pVDr54mt4RzNxi1dQ/PRD
>   6TnjdVhLMpftPv1ELTWCl2tyzSTP3G2LY4dDVstuhzO8+3R9PaIle7CnVZ/2qSSb
>   HVN4Juzn3zSemjRykoZLoV3VLsHU2Cb3m21tCMWB7BFlChd2cYiXeZamJHaypvK+
>   6ZjQgEN7IYeb4ALOIx50WntOC67S29qpG1MZ84TF/OLtVTFWFM+buSCvYpPMMSzS
>   qQIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Private:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAtzAVRzbQWzZi7wjqA/0magqlWQfKJhrfnCuytqwNR0rMKk+h
>   Gx1c+1YaPsN0ZMdBVWyBWJYWzlCjWOKx1vnYgBb3MPXn1QvGkrv+WtXX3VQRsPjW
>   tjaAqLYdjP/m64+pVDr54mt4RzNxi1dQ/PRD6TnjdVhLMpftPv1ELTWCl2tyzSTP
>   3G2LY4dDVstuhzO8+3R9PaIle7CnVZ/2qSSbHVN4Juzn3zSemjRykoZLoV3VLsHU
>   2Cb3m21tCMWB7BFlChd2cYiXeZamJHaypvK+6ZjQgEN7IYeb4ALOIx50WntOC67S
>   29qpG1MZ84TF/OLtVTFWFM+buSCvYpPMMSzSqQIDAQABAoIBAFy/7aYW7Luh98mL
>   O+E1JWP/a+R9+y374UfTIDM5PafhCSpLEwkFfvSKjdNFZwM3l67Gt17A718amPoC
>   HYT5D1MbTaDugKjvw2S75nbbWuZnEGYIN74eLlo9iwy+7I5MOLG7ApZPT6DNPSoN
>   1aWdj1zgwHfDcp91KNwBo6k4NJyxIK0xVSvdcnecpndQ611BUicz3mfMUoa+axDg
>   GROs7IQvEyYMru0E2/lZdURJS1uNg+T3kyBs3zINibwNEFsf8V3e90haWlMjc5MW
>   nNFTo4KWPoHZCWIsyMPZfinjEk/5+DKdFFIQAY7YWUhjnu23Qc4oRu4hb+vTFXQt
>   2FCp2nkCgYEA58QY4zeqhkIPVEWFs/lZDcd/GdwL+/0Dmmm6lUvTQpUG/u0njY9n
>   JOTyvNc+vH3U9FWm3yPKX+HbARC4CMV/x9jU8QIIa0ARcETjh6BQGaEkIReDeXhq
>   X3kwcdSuhqK9nrmp1ocGeIYFGZPrrofJI+1gODCMtdgqt9pbN+8UJxsCgYEAylel
>   rpsFSiAx0bBcZ9kCPHYHpR2kdpcv4iOunpPJLJQ+p0KhCdDA1J7LftlNVS1Pg34W
>   aD3nundbH0D/8B1qnlXvPIDBGOEbnfnKAdf0ti1cznQoBsIzwa56Fcu8MqK9DQXJ
>   AHkmEIdHjPtXjM7fEEuz4kRLjcdirV2T5+KZNYsCgYBCioqaseDDqzO7fjpk8bIf
>   wqc7RXIrZvkh3Dk1pA+DjkXz6yLwAbwbW6BVl3brpzT88Zp3dk8kODQomiQ8YHfP
>   aPG6QFsqb7qSATVSOzTEJv+4gIe+2FOyFZlTFT0GarMGX0fjz+CLue686TtBYLrf
>   FcgKWeYMT4P0RTzrUjj3AQKBgQCf/Rtg6uwMx1X88dCuv/S3r6+ty7ldl39h9Eq+
>   0iWwHOtJPzKr2yaNN525h8JQxgnn84tuEvymAHfJR5DW37uMxG/sS/XiYSOADqC+
>   Qm4YmdeW2ltHtMhNrVKU50nAU9LdeCSNPj1ttjlJ7PY1vOC9Ns5d6xg+W1fXsnUf
>   VZlErwKBgQCLWkrCqsxjKvWBQIE7DgtF5e2eFuuwIWwPODn3uNR7DCrpy7PyBVAd
>   TWrKw+Uu0FmVgEiMWlIWjgse58/ZaBHXzqU5ScsibshJU/tacG+M1uqxAcyr+p03
>   qkSuqbJ6OqUnOWwATrEFLxt5BVnwLlizp9sPggEIJ6mMdOW9J6wONA==
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: where do you set the $priv?

what does the priv.php look like?

Comment: $priv is a variable from the required priv.php file.  It simply contains the private key.

Comment: I found out that the encrypted data was not reaching the php script in-tact due to formatting issues.  I solved this using base64 encoding/decoding.  Still not working like it should.

Comment: What is the data size you are encrypting? Also if this is just to encrypt the data in transit just use HTTPS.

Comment: The data size is not large.  At most 32 bytes.  I am probably going to just use HTTPS in the end.  However, I would still really like to know why this is not working.

Comment: Could you try base64url instead of just base64 for the ciphertext? I think the variables in HTTP POST requests [should be URL encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551320/589259). The RSA padding seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if after this time period it still helps. I found out why through reading source code of jsencrypt. look your code here:

```
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(pubkey);
var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt(plaintext);
```

After this you did

```
var encuser = encryptdata(document.getElementById('username').value);
var encpass = encryptdata(document.getElementById('password').value);
encuser = window.btoa(encuser);
encpass = window.btoa(encpass);
```

You encrypt user then use *btoa()* function encode it to Base64.

But it turns out that the results returned by encrypt.encrypt() are already Base64. Right, *encuser* and *encpass* don't need to be encoded to Base64, They already are!!!

So just **remove**

```
encuser = window.btoa(encuser);
encpass = window.btoa(encpass);
```

I think it should be ok.

BTW I go through all documents offered by JSEncrypt but nowhere mentioned their results are Base64...